# what are cvd and abarsd (listening on ports 8400 and 8402)

Tags: centos, port

I ran nmap on one of our servers and found that tcp ports 8400 and 8402 were open with the services 'cvd' and 'abarsd' listening.  I can't find any information about what these services are.

Can anyone explain what they are, and suggest reasons why I might need or not need them to be running.

The server os is Centos 6, and it's hosted by Rackspace in the UK.

Comment: The names are just from what commonly listens on those ports. Go to the server itself and check what is listening on them.   `netstat -tulpn | grep :840[02]`  You can commonly use `whatis programname` to see some information along with `man programname` on the information netstat returns.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Brian - Got me looking in the right place to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to help from Brian in the comments, I found that the processes were both located in `/opt/simpana/Base`.  'Simpana' used to be a brand of a company called 'Commvault'.  Commvault provide data backup services.

'cvd' is 'Commvault Communications Service'.  I'm not sure what abarsd is yet, but it's also something to do with Commvault.

I think these are services that the Hosting company has installed to provide data backups.